# Cassandra Insert Into; Where goes the table name?

Tags: cassandra

In the documentation it says:

```
INSERT INTO keyspace_name.table_name
( column_name, column_name...)
VALUES ( value, value ... )
USING option AND option
```

In the learn Cassandra e-book it says that if you:

```
INSERT INTO k1.t1 (c1) VALUES (v1);
INSERT INTO k2.t1 (c1, c2) VALUES (v1, v2);
INSERT INTO k1.t1 (c1, c3, c2) VALUES (v4, v3, v2);
```

Then the memtable looks like this:

```
k1 c1:v4 c2:v2 c3:v3
k2 c1:v1 c2:v2
```

Where is the table name? How can we tell columns in different tables apart if they have the same name?

Comment: how did you check whats in the memtable?

Comment: @karthikmanchala Did you read the question? It says that in the learn Cassandra e-book it says that. I didn't check the memtable. Simply reading the book and attempting to make sense of it.